# Add users retrieved from a list to another list of users

Tags: list, powershell, data-manipulation

Currently, I'm getting all of my Active Directory users with this command:

```
$users = Get-AdUser -Filter {(Enabled -eq "True")} -Properties Description
```

After this, I do various things with the list in this way:

```
foreach ($user in $users)
{
   if($user.Description -eq "Admin")
   {
     Write-Host "This is an admin!"
     #Here comes the code that adds the admin to a new list
   }

   if($user.Description -eq "Secretary")
   {
     Write-Host "This is a Secretary!"
     #Here comes the code that adds the secretaries to a new list
   }
}
```

What I want to do however, is add the users in the `foreach` to a new list of users (so I can group them by their description and later do things like show their name, amounts,...)

What would my approach be?

Answer (score 2):

Multiple ways to achieve that. I would probably use the `Where-Object` cmdlet to filter them:

```
$admins = $users | Where-Object Description -eq 'Admin'
$secretaries = $users | Where-Object Description -eq 'Secretary'
```

Another way would be to initialize the array before the foreach loop and add them within the if statement:

```
$admins = @()
$secretaries = @()

foreach ($user in $users)
{
   if($user.Description -eq "Admin")
   {
     Write-Host "This is an admin!"
     $admin += $user
   }

   if($user.Description -eq "Secretary")
   {
     Write-Host "This is a Secretary!"
     $secretaries += $user
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to use your second way you proposed (since that's what i'm trying to implement). But I can't seem to use the properties of a user (like `$user.Name` ) after I'm trying to do things with the arrays?

Comment: Can you explain what you want to do after you have filtered the users?

Comment: My 'end goal' is to have a list of each group that has been filtered in the foreach. This so I can manipulate the lists and retrieve their names and so on. Would you say that PowerShell doesn't allow me to do these kind of list manipulations ?

Comment: You are already there. After you run the script you have a list of each group which you can use to retrieve their names and so on.

Comment: Hmm it's not exactly what I was looking for but thanks anyway

Comment: This is exactly what you are looking for. If you don't know how to use it just explain what you want to do and I can help you....